# How to set value of variable for Azure Pipeline FileTransform conditionally

Tags: azure-pipelines

In my yaml I have a task defined like so:

```
- ${{ each profile in parameters.targetProfile }}:
        - task: FileTransform@1
          inputs:
            folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/${{ Parameters.projectDir }}/*.csdef'
```

The servicedefinition.csdef has a line like this:

```
<WorkerRole name="CRWorkerRole" vmsize="#{VMSIZE}#">
```

If I define the VMSIZE variable from the Azure Pipeline UI, the FileTransform works correctly. However, if I define a variable within the YAML like so:

```
variables:
      VMSIZE: 'Standard_A4_v2'
```

it doesn't work. I have tried without quotes and also assume that the spacing is correct.

Also I am running FileTransform in a loop (see above). I want to set the value of the variable 'VMSIZE' conditionally.

Is this possible?

Update: 05/25/2020: Added the entire yaml file:

```
parameters:
  solution: ''
  cloudServiceProject: ''
  targetProfile: ''

stages:
  - stage: build
    displayName: build solution
    variables:
      buildPlatform: 'any cpu'
      buildConfiguration: 'release'
      VMSIZE: 'Standard_A4_v2'

    jobs:
      - job: build
        displayName: build Job
        pool:
          name: Azure Pipelines
          vmImage: 'windows-latest'
          demands:
            - msbuild
            - visualstudio
            - vstest
            - azureps

        steps:
        - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
          displayName: 'Use NuGet 5.4.0'
          inputs:
            versionSpec: 5.4.0

        - task: NuGetCommand@2
          displayName: 'NuGet restore'
          inputs:
            restoreSolution: '${{ Parameters.solution }}'

        - task: VSBuild@1
          displayName: 'Build solution '
          inputs:
            solution: '${{ Parameters.solution }}'
            platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
            configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

        - ${{ each profile in parameters.targetProfile }}:
            - task: FileTransform@1
              inputs:
                folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/${{ Parameters.projectDir }}/*.csdef' 

            - task: VSBuild@1
              displayName: 'build cloud service project'
              inputs:
                solution: '${{ Parameters.cloudServiceProject }}'
                msbuildArgs: '/t:Publish /p:TargetProfile=${{ profile.name }}
     /p:AllowUnsafeBlocks=true /p:DebugType=None /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:OutputPath=bin\ /p:PublishDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\${{ profile.name }}\\"'
                platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
                configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

        - task: VSTest@2
          displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
          inputs:
            testAssemblyVer2: |
             **\$(buildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
             !**\obj\**
            platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
            configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'       

        - publish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\
          artifact: publishFiles
```

Comment: Did you set the variables at the root? Could you share the entire YAML file? Which kind of condition do you want to apply? Is [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) helpful?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I have added the entire YAML file. I believe the variables are set correctly. The condition is the $ each profile.... I want to update the ServiceDefinition.csdef to a different VMSIZE file for each profile.

Comment: Have you tried set the variables at the `root`? To set the value of the variable conditionally, you may check Expressions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I'm not sure what you mean by root. Do you mean before the 'stages' tag in the yaml above?

Comment: Yes, set variable and stage at the same level.

Comment: This fails with the following error:/build.yaml (LIne: 1, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'variables'

Comment: So you mean the VMSIZE variable only works if you define it in Azure Pipeline UI, it doesn't work when you define in YAML file, correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To run a task in a loop, you can create a template which will have a set of actions, and pass parameters across during your build. For example:

template.yml:

[image]

azure-pipelines.yml:

[image]

Check blog:

https://mattvsts.github.io/2019/05/04/solving-the-looping-problem-in-Azure-DevOps-Pipelines/

Comment: Yes, I tried this but passing the variable this way but how do I pass say the second value in the param pair to FileTransform?

Comment: The values are supposed to be defined in the parameters in azure-pipelines.yml, like param: ["a", "b"].

Comment: Yes, but that value is not passed to FileTransform. That is the problem.

Comment: @PrashantSaraswat Try to put the variable under `jobs`.